spring boot jar and io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl
Where/when/how is the io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl generated?
I have wrapped my Quarkus application into a spring boot bootable jar, because Quarkus' uber-jar packaging has META-INF/services conflicts. To avoid confusion: this is NOT a Spring boot application, I only use Spring boot's all-in-one jar generator for deploying. This generator is totally usable without using Spring itself, I use it for other non-Spring applications as well.
The interesting thing is that if that jar is started on Windows, it works fine. If it is started on a Linux system, it fails with an exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:574)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at io.quarkus.launcher.QuarkusLauncher.launch(QuarkusLauncher.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.launchFromIDE(Quarkus.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:88)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at org.tbee.spotifyDanceInfoQrks.SpotifyDanceInfoQrks.main(SpotifyDanceInfoQrks.java:14)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.launcher.QuarkusLauncher.launch(QuarkusLauncher.java:56)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to resolve nested path
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedPath.resolve(NestedPath.java:130)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.resolve(Path.java:516)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.utils.BuildToolHelper$BuildTool.exists(BuildToolHelper.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.utils.BuildToolHelper.getProjectDir(BuildToolHelper.java:59)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.IDELauncherImpl.launch(IDELauncherImpl.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 11 more

After examination it turns out Quarkus follows a different bootpath on each system, caused by the fact that on Windows it finds a io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl and on Linux it does not. As a result Quarkus.run enters the normal startup on Windows, and the launchFromIDE on Linux. The launchFromIDE tries to determine if it is started from Maven, tries to find some build directory, and fails on a path not found.
io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl is described in the source as a generated class. Where, why, when, how is that generated?

What value is there using Spring Boot - a Tomcat based server environment - inside of Quarkus - a Wildfly based server environment?  You've got all of Spring and you should use it.  Or move to Quarkus and use all of that.  But I'm not understanding the benefit of putting a server inside of a server.

Again, I'm not using Spring Boot itself, only its bootable jar generator, which is a standalone functionality. But it is a valid question why I did not use Spring boot. I have exactly the same application written in spring (https://spotifydanceinfo.softworks.nl/). And for some reason that application keeps restarting. I cannot find the reason, Ive tried many things, so I wanted to find out if the framework, Spring, is a factor. If the Quarkus version also keeps restarting, I need to look at other parts (like the bootable jar). But one chane at a time. Plus, it was educational.

I have figured it out. For some magical reason when the Spring Boot bootable jar was started on Windows, it found the target/quarkus-app/quarkus folder and added that to its classpath. Thus finding the generated-bytecode.jar and the io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl it contained. Once the jar was moved out of the build structure it did not anymore, and showed the same exception as on Linux.
I ended up moving the quarkus build to prepare-package and then immediately an unzip of the generated jars into classes. The maven-jar-plugin then packaged all of it in the bootable jar.

First of all, you cannot include a Quarkus application in Spring Boot as Quarkus is not a library, but a framework that takes full control of the application's lifecycle (in a similar way that Spring Boot does).
As for io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl, that is generated at build time when the application is built, but this detail is not something users ever have to know or interact with.

I am talking about the spring boot "bootable" jar, not a spring boot application. There is a difference. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html And apparently I do need to interact with that class, because it causes the difference in behavior.
